# Error while calling invokeMethod

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi, webm

What could be the problem?

```
invokeMethod(op,        
  "write",        
  inArgs,         //input argument array -> Passing a string
   null);
```

And waht could be the reason for this exception?

```
java.io.IOException
XMLERROR:
java.io.IOException
    at javax.wbem.client.adapter.http.CIMClientXML.call(CIMClientXML.java:391)
    at javax.wbem.client.adapter.http.CIMClientXML.getResponse(CIMClientXML.java:510)
    at javax.wbem.client.adapter.http.CIMClientXML.getFirstResponse(CIMClientXML.java:548)
    at javax.wbem.client.adapter.http.CIMClientXML.invokeMethod(CIMClientXML.java:991)
    at javax.wbem.client.CIMClient.invokeMethod(CIMClient.java:1715)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgets.SMS.SMSPluginClient.write(SMSPluginClient.java:454)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgets.SMS.VirtualFile.write(VirtualFile.java:529)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgets.SMS.SMDRConfigGadget.getSMDRMainFormSubmitData(SMDRConfigGadget.java:1200)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgets.SMS.SMDRConfigGadget.execute(SMDRConfigGadget.java:233)
    at com.novell.emframe.dev.Task.execute(Task.java:505)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgetManager.BaseGadgetInstance.processRequest(BaseGadgetInstance.java:858)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgetManager.BaseGadgetInstance.handleAction(BaseGadgetInstance.java:2384)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgetManager.GadgetManager.processInstanceRequest(GadgetManager.java:1606)
    at com.novell.nps.gadgetManager.GadgetManager.processServiceRequest(GadgetManager.java:1062)
    at com.novell.nps.PortalServlet.handleFrameService(PortalServlet.java:505)
    at com.novell.nps.PortalServlet.processRequest(PortalServlet.java:373)
    at com.novell.nps.PortalServlet.doPost(PortalServlet.java:279)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at com.novell.emframe.fw.servlet.AuthenticatorServlet.service(AuthenticatorServlet.java:332)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.novell.emframe.fw.filter.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're talking about. It would really help if you'd give a short but complete example of what you're doing.

Comment: What *exactly* is the exception?

Comment: Also show the code for reference... that would help alot

Comment: Please don't close this question. Wait a bit until the OP refined his question. It sounds interesting.

Comment: Let me know If anyone need more information...

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about Java Reflection, this is irrelevant. You can't pass an argument of 4000 bytes to a method. The maximum you can pass is 8 bytes. Because of this is the size of the biggest datatypes in Java: `long`, `double`. Even an array is 4 bytes, because of it is an Object, which is represented by a memory pointer.

So, I think you have to search your problem somewhere else...